# Missing artifact com.msg91.sendotp in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, sms-gateway

When i am adding library in spring tool suits i am getting this error:

**'Missing artifact com.msg91.sendotp.library:library:jar:3.2'**

I have added this library in my pom.xml https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.msg91.sendotp.library/library/3.2

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>springdemouser</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springdemouser</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- HERE I AM GETTING ERROR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.msg91.sendotp.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>      
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


<!-- other dependencies here... -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You should add a little more info, especially your pom.xml and everything else which helps to reproduce the problem.
Since you probably can't post your whole project, you could set up a small sample project and try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see couple of things missing in the `pom.xml` as mentioned below

1. If you look at the mvnrepository link for this library it states `this artifact it located at JCenter repository`. Since you have not shared the complete `pom.xml` file it is not clear if JCenter repo has been added. Simple way is to include below in `pom.xml` file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <name>jcenter</name>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

2. you need to add `<type>` as `aar` to your maven dependency else it will try to search for `.jar` file which is not present in the repository

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.msg91.sendotp.library/library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.msg91.sendotp.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

[image]